# Facebook could not load image in meta og:image when share link on Facebook

Tags: apache, facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-debugger

I try use debug tool and result:
`Provided og:image, https:xyz.com/storage/posts/images/1615524371abc.jpg could not be downloaded. This can happen due to several different reasons such as your server using unsupported content-encoding. The crawler accepts deflate and gzip content encodings.`

I use Laravel and Apache Server in Centos.

I don't know how to deal with it. Hope to find the answer here. Thanks

Comment: We are having the same issues, still trying to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: @ArmeniaH Do you have a solution yet?

Comment: Nothing yet sir.